# Nestjs versioning configuration when using Fastify

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-fastify

For performance reasons of a relatively complex Nestjs application, we have chosen to use [Fastify](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance) as our HTTP provider.

We are at a stage where we need to version out api and are running into problems after following instructions on the standard Nestjs [guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning#versioning):

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(fastifyInstance),
    {},
  );

  app.enableVersioning();
```

The error received is:

```
Property 'enableVersioning' does not exist on type 'NestFastifyApplication'.ts(2339)
```

I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere and thought I'd ask and see if anyone else has had the same problem and found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you need to upgrade `@nestjs/common`  because `enableVersioning` does exists in `NestFastifyApplication`:

- https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/d5b6e489209090544a4f39c4f4a716b9800ca6a8/packages/platform-fastify/interfaces/nest-fastify-application.interface.ts#L16
- https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/d5b6e489209090544a4f39c4f4a716b9800ca6a8/packages/common/interfaces/nest-application.interface.ts#L47

Comment: Thanks for that! We're currently using nestjs v7 and it looks like this was introduced in v8.

Comment: indeed. Versioning it's a v8 feature